# How to pass a TSQL parameter to dplyr filter clause?

Tags: r, sql-server, t-sql, dplyr

I'm developing a complex SQL Server parameterized stored procedure.  It takes a parameter `@StudyID` as it's input.  I need to pass the value of this parameter to the `dplyr filter` clause so that only the data for a selected StudyID are returned.  My stored procedure is as follows:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spCodeMeans]
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@StudyID int

AS
BEGIN


-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;



-- Insert statements for procedure here
Declare @sStudy varchar(50)
Set @sStudy = Convert(Varchar(50),@StudyID)
Declare @inquery nvarchar(max) = N'Select
        c.StudyID, c.RespID, c.ProductNumber, c.ProductSequence, c.BottomScaleValue, 
        c.BottomScaleAnchor, c.TopScaleValue, c.TopScaleAnchor, c.StudyDate,
        c.DayOfWeek, c.A, c.B, c.C, c.D, c.E, c.F,
        c.DependentVarYN, c.VariableAttributeID, c.VarAttributeName, c.[1] as c1, 
        c.[2] as c2, c.[3] as c3, c.[4] as c4, c.[5] as c5, c.[6] as c6, c.[7] as c7, c.[8] as c8
        from ClosedStudyResponses c
        --Sensory Value Attributes only for mean and standard deviation analytics.
        where VariableAttributeID = 1
        and c.StudyID =' +@sStudy ;

BEGIN TRY
        --Insert into CodeMeans
        exec sp_execute_external_script
        @language = N'R',
        @script = N'
        library(dplyr)
            OutputDataSet <- data.frame(InputDataSet) %>%
                group_by (StudyID, ProductNumber) %>%
                summarise_all(.funs=c(mean, sd)) %>%
                filter(StudyID == @StudyID) %>%
                setNames(c("StudyID","ProductNumber",
                paste0("c",1:8, "_mean"),
                paste0("c",1:8, "_sd")))
            ',
@params = N'@StudyID int',
@input_data_1 = @inquery,
@output_data_1 = N'OutputDataSet'
WITH RESULT SETS(("StudyID" int, "ProductNumber" int, "c1_mean" int, 
"c2_mean" int, "c3_mean" int, 
"c4_mean" int, "c5_mean" int, "c6_mean" int, "c7_mean" int, "c8_mean" int, 
"c1_sd" int, "c2_sd" int,
"c3_sd" int, "c4_sd" int, "c5_sd" int, "c6_sd" int, "c7_sd" int, "c8_sd" int
));

END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
    THROW;
END CATCH

Select * from CodeMeans;
END
```

How do I ensure that the parameter is passed into the filter clause properly?  If another R package is more optimal for this use case, which one is suggested?

Comment: It sounds like you may want to use the DBI package directly here, see eg dbGetQuery

Comment: Thanks @RolandASc  It's also been suggested that RevoScaleR might get me where I need to be.  Thoughts?

Comment: You are already passing it as a parameter to your SP, do you still need to pass it as a parameter to other call? If not just use string concat. .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not enough reputation to ask in the comments what the error is ... I think there are two things one should do:

1. Define the parameter in the @params (as you did) **and** then provide
   the parameter with an @ in front
2. Remove the @ in the filter function in the R code

I would expect the following to work:

```
exec sp_execute_external_script
        @language = N'R',
        @script = N'
        library(dplyr)
            OutputDataSet <- data.frame(InputDataSet) %>%
                group_by (StudyID, ProductNumber) %>%
                summarise_all(.funs=c(mean, sd)) %>%
                filter(StudyID == StudyID) %>%
                setNames(c("StudyID","ProductNumber",
                paste0("c",1:8, "_mean"),
                paste0("c",1:8, "_sd")))
            ',
@input_data_1 = @inquery,
@params = N'@StudyID int',
@StudyID = @sStudy,
@output_data_1 = N'OutputDataSet';
```